# What font(s) produce the best looking lambda symbol?

Tags: fonts, symbols

Most fonts produce a pretty poor looking lambda, i.e., λ. I want one that has a more "serif" feel as shown in the image below. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda) for lambda also has this image alongside the less appealing lambda. What's interesting is that there appears to be a unicode lambda that looks very similar to what I'm after, i.e., . The funny thing is that this lambda is known as "[Mathematical Bold Small Lamda](https://unicode-table.com/en/1D6CC/)". Anyways, is there a font out there that produces a lambda that looks like the one below, or a non-bold version of the aforesaid unicode counterpart?

[image: this]

Comment: If you click on the image in Wikipedia, it tells you what font was used.  Times New Roman.

Comment: How do you define ‘poor-looking’? There’s absolutely nothing wrong with how my device renders the lambda in your first paragraph (using San Francisco, the default font on iDevices). The lambda you show as an image, which looks like the Times New Roman lambda, doesn’t actually have any serifs, it just has more exaggerated finials (there are fonts that have actual serifs on lambda, like Courier).

Answer (score 0):

Most of modern mathematical writting are done using LaTeX (which is a programmatic language). Once compiled, the font used is called Computer Modern. You can download it there: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/computer-modern.

An alternative if you need svg, is to use this website: https://viereck.ch/latex-to-svg/. Tou just neet to replace the code in the command window by `\lambda` before pressing the download button.

Answer (score 0):

As @Billy Kerr notes in a comment above, if you want a lambda that looks like the one above, just use Times New Roman.

If you want a free font with a serif feel, why not look at the free serif fonts out there?

Here's Source Serif 4, for example: [image]

For an even more pronounced look, try Literata or Noto Serif Display: [image] [image]

For a less pronounced, but still "serify", look, perhaps Source Serif Pro, Noto Serif, or Tinos might do the trick: [image] [image] [image]